# pandas.read_clipboard only reads whole lines not columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, clipboard, ubuntu-18.04

I transferred all my python3 codes from macOS to Ubuntu 18.04 and in one program I need to use **`pandas.clipboard()`**. At this point of time there is a list in the clipboard with multiple lines and columns divided by tabs and each element in quotation marks.

After just trying

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

I'm getting this error: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 8 fields in line 3, saw 11. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.`. And line 3 looks like `"word1" "word2 and another" "word3" ...`. Without the quotation marks you count 11 elements and within quotation marks you count 8.

In the next step I tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')
```

and I'm getting no errors but it results **only in a Series with each line of the clipboard source in one element**.

Yes, maybe it's a solution to write a code for separating each element of a line after this step but because it's working very well under macOS (with just `pd.read_clipboard()`) I hope that there's a better solution.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a "turnaround" for my question. It's **not the exact solution** but because I **just need the elements of one column in an array** I solved it like that:

```
import pyperclip

# read clipboard
cb = pyperclip.paste()

# lines in array
cb_arr = cb.splitlines()

column = []

for cb_line in cb_arr:

    # words in array
    cb_words = cb_line.split("\"")

    # pick element of column 1
    word = cb_words[1]

    column.append(word)

# delete column name
column.pop(0)

print(column)
```

Maybe it helps someone else, too.